# Python/pipTelegramBot/TypeError: TeleBot() takes no arguments

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6531774507:AAGmM98oaCI099weVtXrn_m8YriYbSh_1Ac')

@bot.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
def __start__(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет, я бот помощник</b>', parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Пытался переустанавливать библиотеку, так же пытался менять наименование аргумента. В интернете, когда гуглил, ничего, кроме совета переустановить библиотеку, не смог найти. Подскажите, где я допускаю ошибку. Если не сложно, объясните что я делал не так.

Ошибка:

```
(pythonProject) PS C:\Users\dtita\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dtita\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('6531774507:AAGmM98oaCI099weVtXrn_m8YriYbSh_1Ac')       
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
TypeError: TeleBot() takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, которую вы видите, связана с тем, что вы вызываете конструктор TeleBot с аргументами, хотя в библиотеке telebot конструктор не принимает аргументов. Для того чтобы передать токен бота, вы должны использовать метод bot.token после создания объекта TeleBot. Вот исправленный код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
bot.token = '6531774507:AAGmM98oaCI099weVtXrn_m8YriYbSh_1Ac'
```

Comment: К сожалению это не совсем решило проблему теперь другая ошибка. Попытаюсь решить сейчас сам но на всякий случай здесь тоже оставлю это 


'''(pythonProject) PS C:\Users\dtita\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dtita\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    @bot.message_handlers(commands=['start'])                                     
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                         
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handlers'  
'''

Comment: В этом коде ничего по сути не изменилось: вы всё равно передаёте `TeleBot` один аргумент - пустую строку.